# Current coordinates of an object in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, collision

I need to perform a static collision detection between two objects using C++/OpenGL. I have written the code for the collision detection but this code uses the vertices of the two models as given in their .obj files and not the coords of their current positions (which is what I want).

I have performed to both models a Translate and a Scale transformation and I need to know what are these coordinates right now. I guess it has something to do with transformation matrices etc but how is this combined to the initial coordinates?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have translation t and scaling s, you can simply calculate the actual positions with:

```
world_position = s * model_position + t
```

If you have an arbitrary transformation given as a matrix M, you calculate the position with:

```
world_position = M * model_position 
//where model_position should be a 4d vector with w-coordinate 1
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL doesn't know what a model or a scene is, it just draws points, lines and triangles to a pixel framebuffer.

It's time for you to abandon some or all of the fixed function pipeline. You should no longer build your modelview matrix using glRotate, glTranslate and glScale. Instead you should maintain the matrix yourself, using some math library like GLM or Eigen. This gives you a single instance of the model transformation matrix which you can apply on your original model coordinates for collision testing, but also can be loaded into the modelview matrix using glLoadMatrix (if you also have the view transformation applied) or glMultMatrix in the GL_MODELVIEW matrix mode. Or you go for shaders and use uniforms.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you first draw your objects whith their centroid in the origin (0, 0 , 0)

So when you call the funcion

GLfloat matrixMV[16];

glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrixMV);

the coordinates x, y, z

will be respectively matrixMV[12] matrixMV[13] matrixMV[14]

```
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glRotatef(-25.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glTranslatef(100.0, 50.0, 0.0);
  /*Draw a triangle with centroid in the orign*/
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

      glVertex2f(0.0 , 1.0  );
      glVertex2f(-1.0,-0.27 );
      glVertex2f(1.0 ,-0.27 );

  glEnd();

  GLfloat matrixMV[16];
  glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrixMV);


 double xCenterTriangle = matrixMV[12];
 double yCenterTriangle = matrixMV[13];
 double zCenterTriangle = matrixMV[14];
```

Answer (score 0):

You would actually need to perform the same transformations you did to your coordinates.

If you are using fixed function pipline you might just get the current ModelView Matrix before you start to paint one object via `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m)` into some `GLfloat m[16]` and store the matrices to later apply them to your objects.

To get the multiplication right, here's the way the matrix elements are ordered, when multiplied from the left.

```
   | m[0] m[4]  m[8] m[12] |     v[0]
   | m[1] m[5]  m[9] m[13] | x   v[1]
   | m[2] m[6] m[10] m[14] |     v[2]
   | m[3] m[7] m[11] m[15] |     v[3]
```